# How to select a specific option in a dropdown that has multiple instances?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve :

```
<select name="userId" id="userId">
<option value="1">Charles</option>
<option value="2">Mike</option>
<option value="3">Jeff</option>
<option value="4">Kevin</option>
</select>

<select name="userId" id="userId">
<option value="1">Charles</option>
<option value="2">Mike</option>
<option value="3">Jeff</option>
<option value="4">Kevin</option>
</select>

<select name="userId" id="userId">
<option value="1">Charles</option>
<option value="2">Mike</option>
<option value="3">Jeff</option>
<option value="4">Kevin</option>
</select>
```

For instance, I would like to select the third option (Jeff) of the second "userId" dropdown. I know how to do that for a unique dropdown, but I can't get it to work with multiple dropdowns having the same ID.

I thought I would be able to do it with the following line:

```
$("input[id=userId]").eq(1).val("3");
```

.. but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Charles

Comment: You have same ID for 3 HTML elements. It is wrong  . try to correct that first ( IMHO).

Comment: Agreeing with @Shyju ... "id" elements should be unique within the scope of a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  A DOM element's id is supposed to be globally unique.  Having the same `id="userId"` bit 3 times is broken HTML.  Instead, use:

```
<select name="userId" class="userId">
...
</select>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('select.userId').<whatever jquery you want>;
```

and you'll be all set.

Comment: ended up doing: $("#userId1").val(myVariable); .. and it works like a charm. Thanks!